Sending Data from DynamoDB to AWS MSK
If there is any new data in DynamoDB, I want to send it to AWS MSK. I don't want to use Lambda to read the stream and push the data to AWS MSK.
Is it possible and if it's possible what should I do to put the data to a particular topic?

There is no direct integration. You must use lambda which can trigger from events entering the stream and then push those onto MSK topics.
